# canvas element 3d rotated

Tags: javascript, canvas

We can 3d rotate div for example like this

```
<div class="one">
    <div class="two">
        <div class="tree"></div>
    </div>
</div>

div{width:100px;
    height:100px;}
.tree{
    background-color:red}
.one{
    -webkit-perspective:1000;

}
.two{

       -webkit-transform-style:preserve-3d;
    -webkit-transition: all 2s ease
}
.one:hover>.two{

    -webkit-transform:rotateY(180deg)

}
```

but is there any way to achieve the same efect like this on element drawn on canvas?

Comment: Are you just using images or does it have to work for any canvas elements  e.g. shapes?

Comment: it would be best if it worked for all shapes. But we can make image from canvas so i think just images would be fine

Comment: Is a third party library like [THREE.js](http://threejs.org/examples) usable? I can make some examples for that.

Comment: i dont think so , i havent worked with that library yet.

Comment: @MattRandell has your simplest path to success: Use the 3D version of html5 Canvas == WebGL. A 3D library like Three.js makes the learning curve easier. 3D rotation using 2D canvas can be done by using a 4x4 transformation matrix to find the rotated coordinate for each point on your image and then projecting the results onto a 2D surface. You can start learning about that difficult math process here: http://inside.mines.edu/fs_home/gmurray/ArbitraryAxisRotation/